# What items are in the cooling system loop?

Tags: cooling-system

What items are in the cooling system loop?

I know there's the Radiator, and the Block, but what else?

Comment: This is quite vague: water cooled or air cooled engines?  Any particular make?  Vehicles from this or the previous century?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll also have the:

- Cylinder head(s)
- Water pump
- Thermostat
- Heater core

Some cars also have water pipes in the inlet manifold, and some have water-cooled transmission oil coolers.

You've also usually got an expansion tank, but that's not part of the loop itself.

Answer (score -1):

1. Radiator
2. Thermostat
3. Engine Block
4. Heater Core
5. Water Pump